Time expressions
In reported speech we change
Tomorrow to the day later or after the following or next day
What about in 4 days
4 days later of after and the following 4 days or the next 4 days?

Yes, of course. Why do you think it might be expressed differently?

I don't know hahah. Just I checked many sites and they gave different answers. Thanks

Then in that case, Adam, you can help us all to give you better advice. Those sites will probably have examples, and you should try to write a question that includes those examples and differences. (The more context you give, the better the thread will be.)

Just report the time as you would any other event happening at that time.
If you see a sign (on Tuesday) that says "Festival next Saturday" Then on Wednesday you could report it as "There will be a festival on Saturday". But next Tuesday you could report it as "There was a festival on Saturday".  Note the change in tense.
Similarly if someone says (on Tuesday)  "I'm going to go to the festival in four days."  Then on Wednesday you could report "She said that she is going to go to the festival next Saturday".  But next Tuesday "She said that she was going to go to the festival last Saturday".
Fundamentally, "backshifting" is nothing more than that. You report what happened when she said something. So things that were already in the past get shifted to past perfect.
There is nothing magical about "changing 'tomorrow' to 'the next day'" simply because "tomorrow" has a particular meaning.  You can use any time expression to describe when something happens, the easiest is often the days of the week.
